# python localtime import time

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, localtime

My question is to obtain hours according to the message. But I only
 get the starting time because? time.sleep is to simulate the time of
 incoming messages. Why not give for different time schedules?

```
import time
localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
print "mensage 1",localtime
time.sleep(3)
print "Mensage", localtime
time.sleep(3)
print 'mensage ', localtime
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on the problems you are facing? If I understand, your problem is that each message prints the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `localtime` is a string.  You should instantiate a new time object and call your sleep function on that object.

The documentation for the time methods in Python is [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html).  There are some code samples within the documentation that should give you a starting point.